# Easiest way to decide if List contains duplicates?

Tags: scala

One way is this

```
list.distinct.size != list.size
```

Is there any better way? It would have been nice to have a `containsDuplicates` method

Comment: What is the use case? Remember that `distinct` costs quite a lot, especially when invoked often. And searching for duplicates inevitably leads to sorting. That being said maybe you actually need a `Set` or `Map` (if you want to keep track of duplicates)? Of course you can also use implicit conversions to add `containsDuplicates` to `List[T]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Functional Programming: Does a list only contain unique items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871491/functional-programming-does-a-list-only-contain-unique-items)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: I need to check if a list contains duplicates. This check is done only once when the list is created. The list is never modified after that. The list is small (between 20-50 elements). I could use `Set` as well. I hadn't considered it before.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming "better" means "faster", see the alternative approaches benchmarked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871491/functional-programming-does-a-list-only-contain-unique-items), which seems to show some quicker methods (although note that distinct uses a HashSet and is already O(n)).  YMMV of course, depending on specific test case, scala version etc.  Probably any significant improvement over the "distinct.size" approach would come from an early-out as soon as a duplicate is found, but how much of a speed-up is actually obtained would depend strongly on how common duplicates actually are in your use-case.

If you mean "better" in that you want to write `list.containsDuplicates` instead of `containsDuplicates(list)`, use an implicit:

```
implicit def enhanceWithContainsDuplicates[T](s:List[T]) = new {
  def containsDuplicates = (s.distinct.size != s.size)
}

assert(List(1,2,2,3).containsDuplicates)
assert(!List("a","b","c").containsDuplicates)
```

Answer (score 18):

You can also write:

```
list.toSet.size != list.size
```

But the result will be the same because `distinct` is already [implemented with a `Set`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala). In both case the time complexity should be *O(n)*: you must traverse the list and `Set` insertion is *O(1)*.

Answer (score 4):

I think this would stop as soon as a duplicate was found and is probably more efficient than doing `distinct.size` -  since I assume `distinct` keeps a set as well:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def containsDups[A](list: List[A], seen: Set[A] = Set[A]()): Boolean = 
  list match {
    case x :: xs => if (seen.contains(x)) true else containsDups(xs, seen + x)
    case _ => false
}

containsDups(List(1,1,2,3))
// Boolean = true

containsDups(List(1,2,3))
// Boolean = false
```

I realize you asked for easy and I don't now that this version is, but finding a duplicate is also finding if there is an element that has been seen before:

```
def containsDups[A](list: List[A]): Boolean =  {
  list.iterator.scanLeft(Set[A]())((set, a) => set + a) // incremental sets
    .zip(list.iterator)
    .exists{ case (set, a) => set contains a }
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer. Wouldn't this require more memory though?

Comment: @Jus12, my first suggestion would probably be about the same as distinct except the library one uses a mutable set, I use an immutable one. The second one should have only a bit more memory because of there may be a few iterators created (but that should be a constant numbers of iterators).

Answer (score 2):

```
@annotation.tailrec 
def containsDuplicates [T] (s: Seq[T]) : Boolean = 
  if (s.size < 2) false else 
    s.tail.contains (s.head) || containsDuplicates (s.tail)
```

I didn't measure this, and think it is similar to huynhjl's solution, but a bit more simple to understand.

It returns early, if a duplicate is found, so I looked into the source of Seq.contains, whether this returns early - it does.

In SeqLike, 'contains (e)' is defined as 'exists (_ == e)', and exists is defined in TraversableLike:

```
def exists (p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
  var result = false
  breakable {
    for (x <- this)
      if (p (x)) { result = true; break }
  }
  result
}
```

I'm curious how to speed things up with parallel collections on multi cores, but I guess it is a general problem with early-returning, while another thread will keep running, because it doesn't know, that the solution is already found.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary:**
I've written a very efficient function which returns both `List.distinct` and a `List` consisting of each element which appeared more than once and the index at which the element duplicate appeared.

Note: This answer is a [straight copy of the answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35030746/501113).

**Details:**
If you need a bit more information about the duplicates themselves, like I did, I have written a more general function which iterates across a `List` (as ordering was significant) exactly once and returns a `Tuple2` consisting of the original `List` deduped (all duplicates after the first are removed; i.e. the same as invoking `distinct`) and a second `List` showing each duplicate and an `Int` index at which it occurred within the original `List`.

Here's the function:

```
def filterDupes[A](items: List[A]): (List[A], List[(A, Int)]) = {
  def recursive(remaining: List[A], index: Int, accumulator: (List[A], List[(A, Int)])): (List[A], List[(A, Int)]) =
    if (remaining.isEmpty)
      accumulator
    else
      recursive(
          remaining.tail
        , index + 1
        , if (accumulator._1.contains(remaining.head))
            (accumulator._1, (remaining.head, index) :: accumulator._2)
          else
            (remaining.head :: accumulator._1, accumulator._2)
      )
  val (distinct, dupes) = recursive(items, 0, (Nil, Nil))
  (distinct.reverse, dupes.reverse)
}
```

An below is an example which might make it a bit more intuitive. Given this List of String values:

```
val withDupes =
  List("a.b", "a.c", "b.a", "b.b", "a.c", "c.a", "a.c", "d.b", "a.b")
```

...and then performing the following:

```
val (deduped, dupeAndIndexs) =
  filterDupes(withDupes)
```

...the results are:

```
deduped: List[String] = List(a.b, a.c, b.a, b.b, c.a, d.b)
dupeAndIndexs: List[(String, Int)] = List((a.c,4), (a.c,6), (a.b,8))
```

And if you just want the duplicates, you simply `map` across `dupeAndIndexes` and invoke `distinct`:

```
val dupesOnly =
  dupeAndIndexs.map(_._1).distinct
```

...or all in a single call:

```
val dupesOnly =
  filterDupes(withDupes)._2.map(_._1).distinct
```

...or if a `Set` is preferred, skip `distinct` and invoke `toSet`...

```
val dupesOnly2 =
  dupeAndIndexs.map(_._1).toSet
```

...or all in a single call:

```
val dupesOnly2 =
  filterDupes(withDupes)._2.map(_._1).toSet
```

This is a straight copy of the `filterDupes` function out of my open source Scala library, [ScalaOlio](http://scalaolio.org/). It's located at `org.scalaolio.collection.immutable.List_._`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check for duplicates in a test then ScalaTest can be helpful.

```
import org.scalatest.Inspectors._
import org.scalatest.Matchers._
forEvery(list.distinct) { item =>
  withClue(s"value $item, the number of occurences") {
    list.count(_ == item) shouldBe 1
  }
}

// example:
scala> val list = List(1,2,3,4,3,2)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2)

scala> forEvery(list) { item => withClue(s"value $item, the number of occurences") { list.count(_ == item) shouldBe 1 } }
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: forEvery failed, because:
  at index 1, value 2, the number of occurences 2 was not equal to 1 (<console>:19),
  at index 2, value 3, the number of occurences 2 was not equal to 1 (<console>:19)
in List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```