# Scala: How to check if all items are unique in a Seq?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there a more idiomatic and maybe faster way to check if there are duplicates in a `Seq`, than this:

```
mySeq.size == mySeq.toSet.size
```

Comment: Nope, other than writing your own implicits. See similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691971/easiest-way-to-decide-if-list-contains-duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be faster, because it can terminate early:

```
def allUnique[A](to: TraversableOnce[A]) = {
  val set = scala.collection.mutable.Set[A]()
  to.forall { x =>
    if (set(x)) false else {
      set += x
      true
    }
  }
}
```