# Unusual use of the new keyword

Tags: scala

Thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752677/scala-how-to-check-if-all-items-are-unique-in-a-seq), I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691971/easiest-way-to-decide-if-list-contains-duplicates) from Akos Krivach's comment.

The code in the solution is as follow:

```
implicit def enhanceWithContainsDuplicates[T](s:List[T]) = new {
  def containsDuplicates = (s.distinct.size != s.size)
}

assert(List(1,2,2,3).containsDuplicates)
assert(!List("a","b","c").containsDuplicates)
```

I have never seen that `new` keyword used in this context.

Anyone can enlighten me on how it works?
Is there a name for this pattern?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's so called *anonymous class* which **in this case extends AnyRef** (aka Object). Anonymous classes are used when you need to roll some instance of class, which you don't want to declare. Compiler generates gibberish class name for you:

```
val x = new { def foo = println("foo") } 
x: AnyRef{def foo: Unit} = $anon$1@5bdc9a1a
```

(see, that `$anon$1` to the right)

In fact, you may have seen similar code in Java:

```
Comparator<Integer> comp = new Comparator<Integer>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Integer integer, Integer integer2) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This particular code

```
implicit def enhanceWithContainsDuplicates[T](s:List[T]) = new {
  def containsDuplicates = (s.distinct.size != s.size)
}
```

Defines method (which will be applied implicitly), that, when called, instantiates wrapper class more or less equal to the following:

```
class Wrapper(private val s: List[T]) {
  def containsDuplicates = (s.distinct.size != s.size)
}
```

Comment: Is `new { ... }` the same as `new AnyRef { ... }`?