# How scala traits are implemented in Java?

Tags: java, scala, traits

Ok, I know about javap tool and already looked on decompiled java class files. However there are still some question about how scala traits implemented in java as I'm more .net developer.

```
trait A{
  def foo = "A"
}

trait B extends A{
  override def foo = "B"
  def bfoo = "bfoo"
}

trait C extends A{
  override def foo = "C"
  def cfoo = "cfoo"
}

class D extends A

val d = new D with B with C
```

The interesting thing here is that above d instance is realized in java as

```
D d = new D()
{
  public void bfoo()
  {
    B.class.bfoo(this);
  }

  public void cfoo()
  {
    C.class.cfoo(this);
  }

  public void foo()
  {
    C.class.foo(this);
  }
};
```

What is that construction,

```
... new D() { //definition of methods}?
```

I mean, is it somewhat like, definition of new methods inside instance initializer? I tried to do the same way for myself, and it is compiling, but I didn't find a way to access methods defined that way. I mean inside instance initializers?

**UPDATE**

Ok, here is complete example and what it decompiles to

```
object MainClass{
  def main(args:Array[String]){
    val d = new D with B with C
    println(d.bfoo)
    println(d.cfoo)
    println(d.foo)
  }
}

trait A{
  def foo = "A"
}

trait B extends A{
  override def foo = "B"
  def bfoo = "bfoo"
}

trait C extends A {
  override def foo = "C"
  def cfoo = "cfoo"
}

class D extends A
```

And decompilation of main method:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    D d = new D() {
      public String bfoo() {
        return B.class.bfoo(this);
      }

      public String cfoo() {
        return C.class.cfoo(this);
      }

      public String foo() {
        return C.class.foo(this);
      }
    };
    Predef..MODULE$.println(((B)d).bfoo());
    Predef..MODULE$.println(((C)d).cfoo());
    Predef..MODULE$.println(((C)d).foo());
}
```

Look how it's accessing in-place defined methods through casting. Does it make sense? Cannot understand that part, because when I tried to do it myself, it threw an exception.

Comment: For your info, apart from it being a duplicate: Other JVM-languages are not implemented in Java, they are implemented in JVM bytecode.

Comment: Isn't it right that jvm bytecode can be decompiled to java? That's how it decompiles to java.

Comment: Note also, that [question on such usage of new keyword was asked just today](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23754494/298389).