# Remove unique items from sequence

Tags: scala

I find a lot about how to remove duplicates, but what is the most elegant way to remove unique items first and then the remaining duplicates.

E.g. a sequence (1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2) should be converted into (2, 4).

I can think of using a for-loop to add a count to each distinct item, but I could imagine that Scala has a more elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342596/how-to-get-a-set-of-all-elements-that-occur-multiple-times-in-a-list-in-scala/25342655#25342655) SO post.

Comment: Thanks, however I can't get this to work. I have an Seq[String] =
ArrayBuffer(..), but keep getting ``error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String]
 required: Seq[String]`` when trying to use the function provided in your answer.

Comment: You should add the code you have to your question if it has particular constrains or is something more elaborated, as it stands your question is a duplicate of the one I linked to you, please edit your question.

Comment: I don't know. This is the third time this question has been asked almost within one month. And we have always had the same duplicate answers reposted.

Comment: Obviously I used the wrong terms to search for a solution. You can see how my title differs from the linked solution.

Comment: I know it happens. But I would expect questions like this to be immediately marked as duplicate and closed. It was asked two days ago and @EndeNeu directly linked it. Still people repost the same answers here. That's what bothers me.

Comment: @Kigyo more points, more reputation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also keep in mind that `i => i` can be replaced by `identity` and `map(_._1)` by `keys`, like this:

```
Seq(1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2).groupBy(identity).filter(_._2.size > 1).keys.toSeq
```

This is where a `countByKey` method, such as the one that can be found in Spark's API, would be useful.

Comment: While Mariusz Nosiński answer is (for me) the most intuitive way of tackling this, I gave the accepted answer to this one because it allows to change number of required occurences easily.

Answer (score 2):

`distinct` and `diff` will works for you:

```
val a = List(1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2)
> a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2)

val b = a diff a.distinct
> b: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 2)

val c = (a diff a.distinct).distinct
> c: List[Int] = List(2, 4)
```

In place `distinct` you can use `toSet` as well.

Comment: `distinct` preserves order while `toSet` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward:

```
Seq(1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2).groupBy(i => i).filter(_._2.size > 1).map(_._1).toSeq
```

Using the link from Ende Neu I think your code would become this:

```
 Seq(1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2).groupBy(identity).collect { case (v, l) if l.length > 1 => v } toSeq
```