# How to find duplicates in a list in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

I have a list of unsorted integers and I want to find the elements which are duplicated.

```
val dup = List(1|1|1|2|3|4|5|5|6|100|101|101|102)
```

I have to find the list of unique elements and also how many times each element is repeated.

I know I can find it with below code :

```
val ans2 = dup.groupBy(identity).map(t => (t._1, t._2.size))
```

But I am not able to split the above list on "|" . I tried converting to a `String` then using split but I got the result below:

```
L
i
s
t
(
1
0
3
)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this result.

Reference: [How to find duplicates in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729544/how-to-find-duplicates-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol | is a function in scala. You can check the API [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Int.html)

> |(x: Int): Int
>
> Returns the bitwise OR of this value and x.

So you don't have a `List`, you have a single `Integer` (103) which is the result of operating `|` with all the integers in your pretended List.

Your code is fine, if you want to make a proper `List` you should separate its elements by commas

```
val dup = List(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,100,101,101,102)
```

If you want to convert your given `String` **before** having it on a `List` you can do:

```
"1|1|1|2|3|4|5|5|6|100|101|101|102".split("\\|").toList
```

Comment: ok..Actually i faced a question that I have file having number separated by pipe and i need to remove duplicates and count the number of duplicates.
so you are saying that it can not be done using scala ?

Comment: It can be done if your numbers are given as a String.

List("1|1|1|2|3|4|5|5|6|100|101|101|102").map(_.split("\\|"))

Comment: getting output as [Ljava.lang.String;@4769b07b

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake,  you should use a flatMap instead of a map.

List("1|1|1|2|3|4|5|5|6|100|101|101|102").flatMap(_.split("\\|")).groupBy(identity).map(t => (t._1, t._2.size))

This is working for me

Answer (score 1):

Even easier, convert the list of duplicates into a set - a set is a data structure that by default does not have any duplicates.

```
scala> val dup = List(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,100,101,101,102)
dup: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 100, 101, 101, 102)

scala> val noDup = dup.toSet
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(101, 5, 1, 6, 102, 2, 3, 4, 100)
```

To count the elements, just call the method `size`on the resulting set:

```
scala> noDup.size
res3: Int = 9
```

Comment: OP also needs to know how many times each element appears in the list.

Comment: Thanks, @KarlBielefeldt. Missed that. Then indeed, groupBy is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve the problem

"1|1|1|2|3|4|5|5|6|100|101|101|102".split("\|").groupBy(x => x).mapValues(_.size)

> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(100 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 2, 6 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 102 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 101 -> 2, 3 -> 1)