# code for finding duplicates in an array, Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, duplicates

I'm trying to build a algorithm that can find duplicates in an array, without Using any pre-implemented functions such as "sort" etc.

I have no error but my function does not work… Do you have any idea why? (I'm just starting Scala programming)

```scala
def duplicate(s: Array[Int], length: Int): Boolean = {
  var i = 0 // start counting at value 0
  var j = 0
  var result:Boolean = false
  var isDupli:Boolean = false
  while(j < length && result == false) {
    if (s(i) == s(j)) {
      isDupli = true
      result = true
    }
    j += 1
  }

  result
}

var myArray = Array(2,2,2,2)
duplicate(Array(2,2), 2)
```

I found some code online but people are Using the function sort. My goal is to scroll through the array to find for any duplicates...

Comment: You never increment i so you are only ever comparing the first value to the other values

Comment: I understand thank you! But the problem is that I can't even see the result for the first scan of the array. Result = true would not appear...

Comment: Oh it works. I'm sorry for disturbing. I will try to delete this topic! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find duplicates in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729544/how-to-find-duplicates-in-a-list)

Comment: you can use list.groupBy(identity) that way you will get the count of each element in the list which has more than one it has duplicates.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"will **try** to delete"*, is there anything that prevents you from clicking on the `delete` button? If more answers appear, it might become impossible, or at least more problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations on your code:

- You only look at the first (0th) element, and never increment `i`, so you don't check any of the subsequent elements for duplication.
- The `length` argument is redundant, since we can discover the length of the `Array`, `s`, via its `.length` (or `.size`) attribute. Using the `.length` attribute is safer, because it is always valid. For example, `duplicate(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3), 10)` causes an exception (`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`) since the array doesn't have 10 members.
- You initialize `j` to have the same value as `i`, and then compare `s(i) == s(j)`, so you're always going to get a duplicate on the first element, even if there's no duplication in the array.
- You return `result` (which indicates whether you've found a result), rather than `isDupli` (which indicates whether you found a duplicate). Fortunately, we only need one of these, since finding a result is the same as finding a duplicate.

Here's another version that fixes these problems, and simplifies some code:

```
def duplicate(s: Array[Int]): Boolean = {

  val length = s.length

  var i = 0 // start counting at value 0
  var foundDuplicate = false // Type inference means Scala knows this is Boolean

  // Loop through each member until we've found a duplicate.
  //
  // Note that "!foundDuplicate" is the same as "foundDuplicate == false"
  while(i < length && !foundDuplicate) { 

    // Now compare to each of the remaining elements. Start at the element above i.
    var j = i + 1

    // Loop through each of the remaining elements.
    while(j < length && !foundDuplicate) {

      // If we find a match, we're done.
      if (s(i) == s(j)) {
        foundDuplicate = true
      }

      // Look at the next j
      j += 1
    }

    // Look at the next i
    i += 1
  }

  // Return the result. If we didn't find anything, this will still be false.
  foundDuplicate
}

val myArray1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 8, 9)
val myArray2 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
duplicate(myArray1)  // Returns true
duplicate(myArray2)  // Returns false
```

However, while this is perfectly OK *procedural* code, in *Scala* we can use a much better *functional* style. (Procedural code uses `var`s, `while` loops, etc. which is frowned upon in *Scala*.)

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def duplicate(s: Array[Int]): Boolean = {

  // Helper function to search the array for matches to element at i
  @tailrec // Indicates function is tail recursive.
  def matchElement(i: Int): Boolean = {

    // Helper function to search for a match in remainder of array.
    @tailrec
    def matchRem(j: Int): Boolean = {

      // If j has reached the end of the array, we had no match.
      if(j >= s.length) false

      // Otherwise, does this element match the target? Match found.
      else if (s(i) == s(j)) true

      // Otherwise, look at the next element after j.
      else matchRem(j + 1) // Recursive call
    }

    // If this is the last character of the array, then we can't have a match.
    if(i >= s.length - 1) false

    // Otherwise did we find a duplicate in the remainder of this array?
    else if(matchRem(i + 1)) true

    // Otherwise, perform another iteration looking at the next element.
    else matchElement(i + 1) // Recursive call
  }

  // Start the ball rolling by looking at for duplicates of the first character.
  matchElement(0)
}
```

This might look rather complex, at first glance, but note that it doesn't have *any* `var` declarations or `while` loops. Of course, this a *roll-your-own* solution. There are far simpler methods of achieving this using other `Array` functions.

Answer (score -1):

In your code the variable `isDupli` of no use because anyway you are returning `result` Boolean variable. Also, you are not incrementing variable `i`. You can use `for loop` as below:

```
 def duplicate(s: Array[Int], length: Int): Boolean ={
    var result:Boolean = false; val r = Range(0,length)
    for(i<-r;j<-(i+1) until length; if(s(i)==s(j))) result = true
    result
  }
```

***In Scala REPL:***

```
scala> duplicate(Array(2,2),2)
res4: Boolean = true

scala> duplicate(Array(2,3),2)
res5: Boolean = false

scala> duplicate(Array(2,3,2),3)
res6: Boolean = true

scala> duplicate(Array(2,3,4),3)
res7: Boolean = false
```

Comment: worst case complexity will be n^2

Comment: Each element has to be checked with rest of the elements starting next from the element under consideration to check for existence of duplicate. Can it be improved further?

Comment: if the array is sorted yes it can be!! done in nlog(n) I think by binary search.

Comment: But the question says that we shouldn't use `sort` or any of the readily available methods. But I used `until` here . however it can be replaced with collection `Range(i+1,length)` of course.

Comment: i think author is want's the best solution that's all. But anyway your solution is right and work fine but on the long input it can be a problem

Comment: Thank you a lot everybody, this was very usefull!